# Freeing buttons in a list in OnClick

Tags: android, delphi, automatic-ref-counting, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

What I'm trying to achieve, in simplified form, is to create a list of dynamically created buttons. When clicking on one of the buttons it should be removed from the list and its object should be freed. My approach is :

- Create a `TList<TButton>`
- Create a couple of `TButton` objects and add them to the `TList<TButton>`
- Assign the `Form` as the `Parent` for each of the created `TButton` objects
- Assign a `Position` for each of the created `TButton` objects
- Assign an `OnClick` handler method to each of the created `TButton` objects
- The `OnClick` handler sets the `Sender` `TButton`'s `Parent` to `nil` and deletes it from the `TList<TButton>`, so that ARC can free the `TButton` object that was clicked on.

When I click on one of the dynamically created buttons, I get a "Segmentation Fault". I suspect it is because I am freeing the `TButton` object in its own `OnClick` handler and the class is trying to do some other stuff with it after my handler.

I have tested this on Android. I assume the same will happen on iOS, or any other ARC platform for that matter.

Is there a better/right way to do this, or another approach I should be following to get it working the way I want?

Here is some example code. It is for a form with one design-time button (`Button1`) on it. Clicking this button repeatedly dynamically creates new buttons and adds them to the list.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    ButtonList : TList<TButton>;
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm2.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    pos : Integer;
begin
    pos := ButtonList.IndexOf(TButton(Sender));
    TButton(Sender).Parent := nil;
    ButtonList.Delete(pos);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ButtonList := TList<TButton>.Create;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    pos : Integer;
begin
    pos := ButtonList.Add(TButton.Create(nil));
    ButtonList.Items[pos].Parent := Form2;
    ButtonList.Items[pos].Position.Y := 50 * ButtonList.Count;
    ButtonList.Items[pos].OnClick := ButtonClick;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I click on one of the dynamically created buttons, I get a "Segmentation Fault". I suspect it is because I am freeing the TButton object in its own OnClick handler and the class is trying to do some other stuff with it after my handler.

That is exactly what is happening. After the event handler exits, the RTL still needs access to the button object to finish processing the click and message handling. It is never safe to destroy a UI object from inside of its own events.  So you have to make sure the object remains alive during event handling.

> I have tested this on Android. I assume the same will happen on iOS, or any other ARC platform for that matter.

Yes. And it would also happen on non-ARC platforms if you tried to `Free` the button explicitly, eg:

```
procedure TForm2.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  btn: TButton;
begin
  btn := TButton(Sender);
  ButtonList.Remove(btn);
  {$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
  btn.Parent := nil;
  {$ELSE}
  btn.Free;
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

> Is there a better/right way to do this, or another approach I should be following to get it working the way I want?

You could have the `OnClick` handler post an asynchronous message to the main thread (such as by calling [`TThread.Queue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) inside of [`TThread.CreateAnonymousThread()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread)/[`TTask.Run()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Threading.TTask.Run), or using [`TThread.ForceQueue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) in 10.2 Tokyo and later), and then exit immediately, letting the message handler free the button at a later time when the button is no longer being used, eg:

```
procedure TForm2.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  btn: TButton
begin
  btn := TButton(Sender);
  ButtonList.Remove(btn);

  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TThread.Queue(nil, btn.DisposeOf);
    end
  ).Start;

  { or:
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil, btn.DisposeOf);
  }
end;
```

Alternatively, you could move the button object to another list, and then start a short timer (or use a `TThread.(Force)Queue()` message) to run through that list freeing its objects, eg:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    ButtonList : TList<TButton>;
    DisposeList : TList<TButton>;
    procedure ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DisposeOfButtons;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm2.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  btn: TButton;
begin
  btn := TButton(Sender);
  ButtonList.Remove(btn);
  DisposeList.Add(btn);

  Timer1.Enabled := true;

  { or:
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      TThread.Queue(nil, DisposeOfButtons);
    end
  ).Start;
  }

  { or:
  TThread.ForceQueue(nil, DisposeOfButtons);
  }
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ButtonList := TList<TButton>.Create;
  DisposeList := TList<TButton>.Create;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  btn: TButton;
begin
  btn := TButton.Create(nil);
  ButtonList.Add(btn);
  btn.Parent := Self;
  btn.Position.Y := 50 * ButtonList.Count;
  btn.OnClick := ButtonClick;
end;

procedure TForm2.DisposeOfButtons;
var
  btn: TButton;
begin
  for btn in DisposeList do
    btn.DisposeOf;
  DisposeList.Clear;
end;

procedure TForm2.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  DisposeOfButtons;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Remy. Your first approach of using `TThread.Queue` inside `TThread.CreateAnonymousThread` worked perfectly and I preferred that approach to using a `TTimer`. I had to add a call to `Start()`, though, due to the AnonymousThread being created in a Suspended state.

Comment: I have a question about your use of `DisposedOf()` though. What I am doing instead is to set the `TButton` object's `Parent` to `nil`. As I understand this decrements the `RefCount` to 1 in this case and once the object then goes out of scope ARC destroys the object and frees the memory. According to my understanding `DisposedOf()` destroys the object by calling the destructor, but still leaves the memory freeing to ARC, which will only happen once the `RefCount` reaches zero. Is there a specific reason why you chose to use `DisposedOf()` instead?

Comment: @EdreanErnst it makes the code clearer as to what its intent is. The destructor will still remove the `Parent` reference anyway, decrementing the refcount.